# Regex Forcing 3 minimum Characters in email address

Tags: regex, validation

I have regular expression `^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]{1}[äöüÄÖÜß\w\._%+-]{1}[äöüÄÖÜßa-zA-Z0-9]{1}@[\wäöüÄÖÜß]{1}[äöüÄÖÜß\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$` for Email validation which accepts minimum 3 characters before @ sign, I want to allow one or more characters before @ sign. refer below explanation.
`abc@gmail.de` works fine but `ab@gmail.com` doesn't work. I want user to enter atleast 1 character before @ sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit `{1}` from the pattern as the character class by itself without a quantifier matches 1 char. Currently you are matching exactly 3 characters, so you can just use a single character class and repeat that 1 or more times.

Note that you don't have to escape the dot in the character class.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]*@[\wäöüÄÖÜß][äöüÄÖÜß\w.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1PsQWH/1)

Comment: Thanks this works fine but issue is I have to make sure first character shouldn't be a special character.

Comment: @AirCodeOne I have updated the pattern to not start with a "special" character.